# Append custom post type to category url

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am trying to get a url when click on the link that has `www.website/custom_post/category/post_name`

What I currently have is `www.website/category/post_name`.

My current code

```
  <?php
      
  $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
        $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => $post_type,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_status'    => 'publish'
                );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $my_categories = array();
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if(!in_array($term->term_id, $my_categories))
                    $my_categories[] = $term->term_id;
                }   
            endif;  
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    if(sizeof($my_categories)) { ?>
    <h6>show only posy cats of post type test</h6>
    <?php
        foreach ($my_categories as $term_id) {
            $category = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'category');
            if($category->slug!="all-articles") {
            ?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>">
           <?php echo $category->name; ?>
      </a></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about php but you can also do it with php too by making a Router. You can search in google for it.

But also you can do it with .htaccess file and path redirects and rewrite rules. Here is code i prepared for your example write it into .htaccess in your server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite rule for www.website/custom_post/category/post_name
RewriteRule ^custom_post/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&post_name=$2 [L,QSA]

# If the request is not a file or directory, pass it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, If i have multiple custom post types would this solution above work ?

Comment: So it's working like when you see ([^/]+)/([^/]+) somewhere in that path. It means you can write anything else forward of it. Then create first path and forward of it means multiple. Also yes you can add multiple of it but i don't know it for POST Request. For requests it works different because web browsers work with Request and Response logic. Here is a basic tutorial for router: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-routing-system-in-php/